# Does YouTube accept AviSynth .avs scripts for uploading?

Tags: video-quality, youtube, file-formats, compression, avisynth

Without reencoding videos first? Is it possible to browse for .avs file and upload it, provided AviSynth is properly installed locally?

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @MarianD yes, it simply uploads the script file first, then tries to treat it like video, and fails; it doesn't open it locally and doesn't begin to stream it to youtube server; that was a naive assumption; perhaps a dedicated upload tool might solve that

Comment: So you answered your own question. ;-) Why to search for a dedicated upload tool, you may convert it locally and then upload it as a regular multimedia file.

Comment: It's not on this list, and therefore not possible: https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en

Comment: @Matt yes it is. When an external program opens avs script, it actually sees it as a generic AVI file with no compression

Comment: It's not possible because the `.avs` script must be opened and processed locally, so uploading a video through your browser would never work.  A dedicated-YouTube-uploading tool in theory maybe could work, but that either would imply that it'd be uploading uncompressed or losslessly compressed video (no way) or it'd be re-encoding the video for upload (and there'd be no guarantee that the YouTube server wouldn't re-encode the video again anyway, and encoding locally likely would be a lot slower.